# silverlight : Checkbox checked/unchecked with another checkbox checked/unchecked

Tags: silverlight, checkbox

I have few checkbox's  (8 of them) one of which is for Enable/Disable other 7 checkbox's.

for that I have written as,

```
IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ControlchkEnable, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}"
IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=ControlchkEnable, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}"
```

in every dependent CB's.
Now enable/Disable is working fine,
but if **Master checkbox is unchecked, then other checkbox's are not getting unchecked**, they are just getting disabled.

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to change the mode to TwoWay?

Comment: I don't want to change Master CheckBox's state upon dependent CheckBox's, and that is what happening is Mode is Changed to TwoWay.

Comment: have you tried removing IsEnabled binding and see what happens?

Comment: I threw together a sample to test your issue and am having the same problem. Interestingly enough I also tried binding the master and child checkboxes to a ViewModel boolean property with the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the checkbox is disabled you cannot change value.

To do that in MVVM, you have to change values before disabled the main checkbox :

**c#**

```
/// <summary>
/// Bind to IsChecked of "ControlchkEnable" element (TwoWay)
/// and bind to IsEnabled of each of other 7 checkbox's (OneWay)
/// </summary>
public bool ControlchkEnable
{
    get { return _controlchkEnable; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _controlchkEnable) return;
        _controlchkEnable = value;
        // Before informing the checkboxes are disabled,
        // pass their values ​​to uncheck
        if (!_controlchkEnable)
        {
            Check1 = false;
            // Check2 = false;
            // Check...= false;
        }
        // Raise UI that value changed
        RaisePropertyChanged("ControlchkEnable");
    }
}
private bool _controlchkEnable;

/// <summary>
/// Bind to IsChecked of one of other 7 checkbox's (TwoWay)
/// </summary>
public bool Check1
{
    get { return _check1; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _check1) return;
        _check1 = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Check1");
    }
}
private bool _check1;
```

**Xaml :**

```
<!-- Main checkbox -->
IsChecked="{Binding ControlchkEnable, Mode=TwoWay}"

<!-- Other checkbox's -->
IsEnabled="{Binding ControlchkEnable, Mode=OneWay}"
IsChecked="{Binding Check1, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: Exactly that is what I was trying. Thanks a lot.
One minor  modification :
in **Setter** for **Check1** we need put
`_check1 = value;` in place of `_controlchkEnable = value;`

Comment: You're right, I made ​​a mistake "copy and paste" ... thank you :)